# Why artificially change access/modification times with touch -am?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

So I've learned that with `touch -a` and `touch -m` one can change access and modification times to a file respectively.

But why?

Wikipedia says:

> " An updated access or modification date can be important for a
>   variety of other programs such as backup utilities or the make
>   command-line interface programming utility."

But I still don't get it.

Anyone has 1 or 2 real-life scenarios?
Also, can this command be misused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one of the wikipedia examples states that it's useful with the make command. Make is a program used to execute Makefiles which contain a build script for any source code and if you run the command, it stored the current Makefile's modification time inside the directory.

Now say that you want to rebuild the source for whatever reason. if you were to run make again it would tell you that there's nothing to do, since it has been run already. So you can run `touch -m "source.file"` to simulate a file modification. Running make a third time would then recognize the change and rebuild the source code.

Another example would be to force a backup. If you're running a backup utility that for example backs up files based on when they have been modified. You could force the program to back up (or exclude from the backup) a file by changing it's modification time.

> create the false impression about the age of a file
>
> for example for use in backup schemes. You might want to not update a backup with a newer one since they're identical, or since the changes are irrelevant compared to the expense of updating a backup on, say, a slow line to a remote host. To achieve this, you have the simple option of marking the backup file with a newer timestamp, not faking but declaring that the validity timestamp of that file is now a different one.
>
> The impression about the age of the file is now indeed false, but its meaning is real and legitimate.

- Answer from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109003/what-are-the-legitimate-uses-of-the-touch-command) question where you can find even more examples